# Executing an Insert on a Custom Graph Causing Error

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to insert a new record into a custom table in the database. This is being performed through a graph extension onto the SO graph. The code is as follows:

```
    public PXAction<PX.Objects.SO.SOOrder> addToDatabase;

    [PXButton(CommitChanges = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Send to Manufacturing")]      
    protected void AddToDatabase()
    {
        try
        {
            Flow2 graphWO = PXGraph.CreateInstance<Flow2>();
            EMPWorkOrder wo = null;
            foreach (PXResult<SOLine, InventoryItem> line in PXSelectJoin<SOLine, LeftJoinSingleTable<InventoryItem, On<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<SOLine.inventoryID>>>,
                Where<SOLine.orderNbr, Equal<Current<SOOrder.orderNbr>>>>.Select(Base, Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr))
            {
                PXCache sender = Base.Transactions.Cache;
                SOLine soLine = (SOLine)line;
                InventoryItem item = (InventoryItem)line;
                SOLineExt lineExt = sender.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(soLine);
                if (lineExt.UsrisSentToManufacturing != true)
                {
                    wo = new EMPWorkOrder();
                    wo.Soid = Base.Document.Current.OrderNbr;
                    wo.ItemCD = item.InventoryCD;
                    wo.LineNbr = soLine.LineNbr;
                    wo.QtyReceived = 0;
                    wo.DateReceived = null;
                    wo.QtyComplete = 0;
                    wo.QtySentToInventory = 0;
                    wo.RouteId = "0";
                    wo.KitId = -1;
                    wo.IsStarted = false;
                    wo.NoteID = Guid.NewGuid();

                    graphWO.Document.Insert(wo);
                    graphWO.Actions.PressSave();
                    graphWO.Clear();

                }
            }
            throw new PXException("Successfully moved to Manufacturing");
        }
    }
```

When executing the code, the error I receive is the following:

> Error#14: Inserting 'EMPWorkOrder' record raised one or more errors. Please review.

When I go into the trace, this is the information it gives me:

> 12/16/2016 1:44:23 PM Error: 
>   Error #14: Inserting  'EMPWorkOrder' record raised one or more errors. Please review.
>
> at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry_Extension.AddToDatabase() 
>     at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<.ctor>b__0(PXAdapter adapter)
>
> at PX.Data.PXAction`1.a(PXAdapter A_0)
>
> at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext()
>
> at PX.Data.PXAction`1.d__31.MoveNext()
>
> at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.tryExecutePendingCommand(String viewName, >String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, Object[] searches, Object[] >parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, >Boolean& closeWindowRequired, Int32& adapterStartRow, Int32& adapterTotalRows)
>
> at PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments)

Is there any reason that my record wouldn't be inserting into the custom table I made? If you need any other information to develop a resolution to this issue, please feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eric, you most likely get this error because of some empty field or fields (with no value or null value assigned) decorated with the PXDefaultAttribute. While running the code under debugger, you should get access to a more detailed exception through the InnerException property of the originally thrown exception.

On a side note, let me also advise you to add SOLine.orderType field in Where clause of your BQL query in the beginning of action delegate, as there are 2 key fields defined for the SOOrder DAC has: OrderType and OrderNbr

Comment: Ruslan, you were correct. I did miss a field, and I forgot to set the Id field to PXDBIdentity. After setting the wo.ItemCD field and changing the ID field in the DAC to PXDBIdentity, I am still getting the same error when I attempt to run the .PressSave() command.

Comment: Eric, did you check what's stored in the InnerException property of the originally thrown exception? `PXUIFieldAttribute.GetErrors(wo)` should also return list of raised errors. Also you should never assign any value to NoteID field.

Comment: Ruslan, thanks I will try the PXUIFieldAttribute.GetErrors if I can. Right now I cannot get Visual Studio to attach to my browser so that I can debug. I'm not sure how to fix that right now. I'll let you know the results, but it might not be for a bit. Working on a different section of code that is causing issues right now.